# Lost badges in Arqade

Tags: support, badges

Has there been a recent change or something on the site that would have caused me to lose my badges on Arqade?? I've lost all the badges that I specifically gained on this site - about 5, including one silver badge. Can anyone tell me why this has happened and whether they will return or if I have to re-earn them?

I saw [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224352/lost-badges-in-stack-overflow-account-when-added-a-new-login-openid) from a couple years ago that mentioned a problem with OpenID and losing badges on Stack Overflow, but I'm not sure if this is the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [main user account](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/75072/johonn) still has these badges. Badges are accrued separately on the main site and on meta, even though the reputation is directly linked to each other.